# ExtJS 4.0.7 to 4.1 Migration : Adding Components Dynamically Failed

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a requirement where a user must be able to split a given panel into two parts (horizontally/vertically) dynamically.
I achieved the same in ExtJS 4.0.7 using this code

```
splitPanel: function(direction)
{
    var subWizard1 = Ext.create('Ext.ux.SplitPanel', {
        contextMenuItems: this.contextMenuItems
    });

    var subWizard2 = Ext.create('Ext.ux.SplitPanel', {
        contextMenuItems: this.contextMenuItems
    });


    this.layout = {
        type: direction,
        align: 'stretch'
    };

    this.add([ subWizard1, subWizard2]);


    subWizard1.on({
        userSelection:
        {
            scope: this,
            fn : function(sourceEvent,sourceObject,options)
            {
                this.fireEvent('userSelection',sourceEvent,sourceObject,options);
            }
        }
    });
    subWizard2.on({
        userSelection:
        {
            scope: this,
            fn : function(sourceEvent,sourceObject,options)
            {
                this.fireEvent('userSelection',sourceEvent,sourceObject,options);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The definition of Ext.ux.Split Wizard : -

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.SplitPanel', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',


    mixins: {
        splitPanelController: 'Ext.ux.SplitPanel.Controller'
    },

    initComponent : function() {    
        var config = {
            flex: 1,
            autoDestroy: true,
            autoRender: true,
            listeners: 
            {
               render: function() 
               {
                   //Adding a Context Menu Click Event Listener. Since this is a simple plain panel without any items (unlike grid,tree etc) 
                   // we need to add the contextmenu listener on the body DOM . Ext.getBody() returns the current document body as an Ext.element
                   this.body.on({
                       contextmenu: 
                       {
                           scope: this,
                           // disable the browser's default context menu
                           stopEvent: true,                    
                           fn:function(sourceEvent, sourceObject, options)
                           {
                               this.genContextMenu(sourceEvent, sourceObject , options);
                           }
                       } 
                   });
               }
            }
        };


        this.elemRepID = "";

        Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
        Ext.ux.SplitPanel.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);

        this.addEvents('userSelection');
    },
    onRender: function()
    {
        Ext.ux.SplitPanel.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
    }


});
```

'Ext.ux.SplitWizard.Controller' which is mixed in 'Ext.ux.SplitWizard' has the "splitPanel" Method which is called from a context menu on the panel. 
This way user can right click on the panel where a contextmenu pops up using which he can split the panel horizontally/vertically which calls the 
'splitPanel' method accordingly.

The genContextMenu method :

```
genContextMenu : function(sourceEvent, sourceObject , options) {

    var menuItems = new Array();

    menuItems.push({
        text : 'Split',
        iconCls : 'ContextMenu-Split-icon',
        menu : {
            items : [ {
                text : 'Horizontally',
                scope : this,
                iconCls : 'ContextMenu-Split-Vertical-icon',
                handler : this.splitPanel.bind(this,'vbox')
            }, {
                text : 'Vertically',
                scope : this,
                iconCls : 'ContextMenu-Split-Horizontal-icon',
                handler : this.splitPanel.bind(this,'hbox')
            }, {
                text : 'UndoSplit',
                scope:    this,
                iconCls : 'ContextMenu-Undo',
                handler : this.undoSplit
            } ]
        }
    });

    var wizardContextMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        margin : '0 0 10 0',
        floating : true,
        renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
        items : menuItems,
        listeners: 
        {
           render: function() 
           {
               // Disabling browser context menu from popping when right clicked on menu body.
               this.body.on({
                   contextmenu: 
                   {
                       scope: this,
                       stopEvent: true,                    
                       fn:    Ext.emptyFn                           
                   } 
               });
           }
        }
    });

    wizardContextMenu.showAt(sourceEvent.getXY());
}
```

This was working fine in 4.0.7. But when I migrated to 4.1 the

```
this.add([ subWizard1, subWizard2]);
```

failed with "container is undefined" . Is this the right way to do it ?? or is there any better way?